# Is it the correct way to initialize SQLite in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im working on android studio and i encountered a problem, I cant initialize my sqlite instance in my DataHandler class but I can initialize it in my MainActivity class.

Example:
MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

//valid
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("Database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE , null); //...
```

in datahandler class:

```
public class DataHandler {
public static String[] names,dates;

//invalid: cannot resolve method
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("HMDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE , null);
```

so, i did this

in main activity:

```
public SQLiteDatabase getSqLiteDatabase() {
    return sqLiteDatabase;
}
```

in datahandler:

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = mainActivity.getSqLiteDatabase();
```

is this the correct way? is there any better method? sry if hard to understand

Comment: No. That is not the best way to do that.  It's hard to say what the problem is but 1st guess is that you're not importing `SQLiteDatabase` in your  `DataHandler` class.  However, it's more common to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` for this.

Comment: I assume here you can grab more info https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use Singleton Pattern as described here 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class PostsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
  private static PostsDatabaseHelper sInstance;

  // ...

  public static synchronized PostsDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new PostsDatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
   * Make a call to the static method "getInstance()" instead.
   */
  private PostsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

And in your `MainActivity` use it like

```
// In any activity just pass the context and use the singleton method
PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
// or
PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
// or
PostsDatabaseHelper helper = PostsDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
// Do something with data via Cursor and
helper.close();
```

This approach perfect suits to get access to the database from different places of you app  like Service, Fragment and etc...

Comment: I get "error: PostsDatabaseHelper is not abstract and does not override abstract method onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase,int,int) in SQLiteOpenHelper"

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the correct way?

Did it throws any errors when project is running ?

This is how I normally do in **DatabaseHandler** (just sharing)

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DATA.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "TITLE";
    public static final String COL0 = "ID";
    public static final String COL1 = "TODO";
    public static final String COL2 = "DETAIL";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, TODO TEXT, DETAIL TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop if database is exists" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

In **MainActivity**, declare this line

```
DatabaseHandler db;
```

In `onCreate` method, initialize **DatabaseHandler**

```
db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

When you want to use  `SQLite` database, make sure you have this line

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: ca i use my way to obtain file from mainactivity

Comment: what file did you mean?